# How often do the Diablo 3 forum character profiles update?

Tags: diablo-iii

Example: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/profile/Rhyinn-1349/hero/57466397

How often does this update? Is it every time you log in to Diablo 3? Is it only during a certain time of day?

I vaguely remember that World of Warcraft armory updates every time you log out, does Diablo 3 work the same way because it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: I don't know if it updates right after you log out, but I have noticed it gets updated shortly thereafter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because answer of WizardLizard isn't correct **for now**:

After release of 2.2 patch, site's profile updated (after logout) with some random delay (as long as 1+ day, up to ~30 hours) in a two "waves" - separately gear and skills

Answer (score 2):

In normal condition (no lag, bug on Blizzard's Server etc.), the profile updates everytime you log off Diablo 3. If you don't see it updates try to [hard refresh the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Bypassing_cache).

Comment: Every auto save you come into contact with will repopulate your characters current state.